# Display alternate column value in gridview column

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have gridview column 'Assignment Result' which is bound to data column status. How to get the gridview to display 'Untouched' when the bound data column value is 'Fresh'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper method:

```
public static string FreshLabel(object value)
{
    if ((string)value == "Fresh")
    {
        return "Untouched";
    }
    return "Touched";
}
```

and then inside your data bound column use it:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# FreshLabel(Eval("SomeColumn")) %>' />
```